# Converting Character to Date in SAS

Tags: sas

If I have an input char like:

```
JULY 3, 2013
```

how can I turn this into a `date type` data in SAS? This is what I've tried so far:

```
input(trim(t1.date), MMDDYY10.)
```

However, this just gives me `.` in all entries.

Answer (score 4):

This seems  to work

```
data have;
 dt="July 3, 2013";
run;

PROC SQL noprint;
 CREATE TABLE want AS
 SELECT input(dt,ANYDTDTE20.) as new_date format=mmddyy10.
 FROM have;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Indeed; this is in fact the -only- way to read this in, short of hand-coding it (ie, breaking it up and making it into a normal format).  The [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/63324/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n04jh1fkv5c8zan14fhqcby7jsu4.htm) gives an example of this, and indicates "none" for the equivalent informat.